# Set up https magento

Tags: magento-1.9, https

I'm trying to get my site to https, but I'm getting file mix error, I made the changes I found there but did not get results. Is there any additional configuration?

**ERROR:**

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mydomain.com.br/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.mydomain.com.br/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/styles.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Magento config**

[image: Magento Config]

Comment: Do you have SSL Certificate on your server?

Comment: Yes, by incapsula

Answer (score 3):

Force HTTPS throughout the store may fix your issue. You can do that by specifying HTTPS URL in unsecure base URL as well. It may be caused by loading the css with unsecure base URL somewhere in your code directly.

Or just use the condition `Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()` to check if HTTPS is enabled and get HTTPS URL for the css declaration you've done.

Comment: Depending on your customization(s), you may have to dig through your code to find every instance that you pulled a url and make sure it is secure.  In the case of your example (a `skin_css` file), it should be resolved with this answer from @vignesh

Comment: Also - just do a double check to make sure your store and website url configs are updated when forcing this as well.  Simple, but I have missed one before.